# Creating comma separated string from custom collection

Tags: c#, .net, linq, generics

I have `List<Accrual>` and `List<Brand>` (and many other similar objects) as mentioned below.  I need to create a comma separated string from a `List<string>` using `String.Join`

```
    public static string GetCommaSeparatedString(List<string> input)
    {
        return String.Join(",", input);
    }
```

1. In the case of `List<Accrual>` I need to pass a `List<Description>` to
   the method
2. In the case of `List<Brand>` I need to pass a `List<Name>`
   to the method

How can we achieve it in the most readable way with least number of lines of code?

Note: I am using .Net 4.0

**Class Examples**

```
public class Accrual
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

}

public class Brand
{
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Why not override the `ToString()` of both the classes?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Firstly, you can override `ToString` method:

```
public class Brand
{
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name;
    }
}

void Method()
{
    var brands = new List<Brand>()
    {
        new Brand { Number = 1, Name = "a" },
        new Brand { Number = 2, Name = "b" }
    };
    // outputs: a,b
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", brands));
}
```

Secondly, you can use Linq to get names, and then join them:

```
var brandsNames = brands.Select(i => i.Name);
string joinedNames = string.Join(",", brandsNames);
```

If you really need generic method for that then you can use this one (although it gives you nothing, at least in this case), this is still using overrriden `ToString` method:

```
public static class Formatter
{
    public static string GetCommaSeparatedString<T>(IEnumerable<T> input)
    {
        return string.Join(",", input);
    }
}
// and then
string brandsStrings = Formatter.GetCommaSeparatedString<Brand>(brands);
// or just
string brandsStrings = Formatter.GetCommaSeparatedString(brands);
```

Comment: Using `ToString()` is just the first step, the next step is to create a generic method, I hope you update with that.

Comment: Well, why do you need to use generic method anway? I think it's overkill in this case, especially that it just a *shorthand* for `string.Join(",", collection`)

Comment: I think that's what the OP wants, he has only 1 method receiving an argument of different list as he described in his question. I don't know why the OP wants such a thing while we can be satisfied with what `LINQ` does.

Comment: OK then, I've edited my answer to include generic method, it certainly looks like generic stuff is not needed (in this case).

Answer (score 3):

Well, first I'd change `GetCommaSeparatedString` method signature to support `IEnumerable<string>` instead of `List<string>` and turn it into an extension method:

```
public static string GetCommaSeparatedString(this IEnumerable<string> input)
{
    return String.Join(",", input);
}
```

Then simply do:

```
var accDescrs = listAccruals.Select(x => x.Description).GetCommaSeparatedString();
var brndNames = listBrands.Select(x => x.Name).GetCommaSeparatedString();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static string SeparateByCommas<T, TProp>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Expression<Func<T, TProp>> expression)
{
    var memberExpression = expression.Body as MemberExpression;
    if (memberExpression == null)
        return string.Empty;

    var propName = memberExpression.Member.Name;
    return source.Aggregate(new StringBuilder(), (builder, t) =>
           {
               builder.Append(typeof (T).GetProperty(propName).GetValue(t).ToString());
               builder.Append(",");
               return builder;
           }).ToString();
}

var test = new List<Brand>
{
   new Brand
   {
     Number = 1,
     Name = "a"
   },
   new Brand
   {
     Number = 2,
     Name = "b"
   }
};


string separateByCommas = test.SeparateByCommas(brand => brand.Name);
```